# Script tag not loading external JS file on MacBook

Tags: javascript, html

I have recently started learning HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. When I try to source the JS file, it doesn't seem to load anything. I created this dummy project where it just outputs "Hello World" in the chrome console to see if there was anything I was missing. Tested the same code on my Windows machine and it worked, however, on my mac M1 it didn't. JavaScript is allowed on this machine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Woop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The "app.js" just outputs "Hello World" as stated, I have checked that the routes are correct and the name is correct. I tried to switch default browsers but no luck.

Does anyone have an answer to this problem?

Comment: Could you post contents of the `app.js` script as well?

Comment: This is the contents, `console.log("Hello World")`, created the file to test if i was doing anything wrong.

Comment: Can you confirm if your js is correct by changing external script tag into ```<script>{console.log("Hello world")}</script>``` ?

Comment: I would also ask for OS version and browser version that are being in use during this experiment. I assume Chrome was used in both cases, wasn't it?

Comment: I have been using the script tag to write the code instead of giving a source, so I originally tried `console.log("Hello world")` and it worked, just not letting me use the external JS file. Everything is up to date as well, OS and Chrome. Chrome was used in these tests.

Comment: open the chronme dev console, and check if there is any error in the console?